# How to Recursion using map in react

Tags: reactjs

I have JSON data and I want to read all the data and make a dropdown list.
Here is the sample code I have written. In this code only 2nd level it is showing. I want all levels.

```
{
                                menu_data.map((menu)=>(
                                    menu.children ? 
                                    <div class="menu-item sub-nav">{menu.name}
                                         <div class="menu-container">{menu.children.map((child)=>(<div class="menu-item"><a href={child.url}>{child.name}</a></div>))}</div>
                                    </div>
                                    :
                                    <div class="menu-item">{menu.name}</div>
                                       
                                ))
                            }
```

`The JSON data looks like`

```
[{
   "name": "ABC",
   "url": "/abc.html"
},
{
   "name": "XYZ",
   "children": [{
         "name": "PQR",
         "url": " /pqr.jsp"
      },
      {
         "name": "MOB",
         "url": "/hello"
      },
      {
         "name": "TOC",
         "children": [
                {
                 "name": "LOL",
                 "url": "/hello"
              },
              {
                 "name": "RST",
                 "url": "/hello"
              },
              {
                 "name": "NULL",
                 "url": "/hello"
              }
         ]
      },
         ]
      }
   ]
},
{
   "name": "def",
   "url": "/def.html"
}
]
```

please refer to this screenshot. in this way, I want to show.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5Xu1.png)

1. Anyone has any idea.

   ```
    How to solve this problem.
   ```

Comment: This question looks very similar to yours: [Recursive component rendering based on a tree menu object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357639/recursive-component-rendering-based-on-a-tree-menu-object/66366044#66366044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `menu_data` also had an issue:

```
const menu_data = [
    {
        name: "ABC",
        url: "/abc.html",
    },
    {
        name: "XYZ",
        children: [
            {
                name: "PQR",
                url: "/pqr.jsp",
            },
            {
                name: "MOB",
                url: "/hello",
            },
            {
                name: "TOC",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "LOL",
                        url: "/hello",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "RST",
                        url: "/hello",
                    },
                    {
                        name: "NULL",
                        url: "/hello",
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: "def",
        url: "/def.html",
    },
];
```

Define a recursive menu renderer as below:

```
    const renderMenu = (menu) => {
        return menu.map((item) => (
            <>
                {item.children ? (
                    <div className="menu-item sub-nav">
                        {item.name}
                        <div className="menu-container">
                            {renderMenu(item.children)}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div className="menu-item">
                        <a href={item.url}>{item.name}</a>
                    </div>
                )}
            </>
        ));
    };
```

Render it like below:

```
    return <div className="menu-container">{renderMenu(menu_data)}</div>;
```

Working Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-cloud-hw5pl?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This seems correct, but it would be worth noting that since you are using plain javascript function calls, no components get created.

Comment: @JanezKuhar,it is working fine. I have added a sandbox URL as well

Comment: But I want print the item structure like <div class="menu-container">
<div class="menu-item">ABC</div>
  <div class="menu-item sub-nav">
    XYZ
    <div class="menu-container">
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">PQR</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">MOB</a></div>
    <div class="menu-item sub-nav">TOC
        <div class="menu-container">
            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">LOL</a></div>
            <div class="menu-item"><a href="#">RST</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <div class="menu-item">DEF</div>
</div>

Comment: Intend is missing due to adding comments. plz, follow the proper indent. I want to put the value in this way

Comment: @Sonunigam Bar, I have updated the answer check. Please mark this answer once you have check it. Thanks!